# VBA Help: I am looking for the best method to open 7 files at once (for the last week)

Tags: excel, vba, loops, date

Here is my code below that opens up yesterdays file Tuesday-Friday and the last 3 days on a Monday.
There is now a need to make a weekly version of this and i feel the code may get too long.
Is there a better way to do this then recreating the loop 7 times?

I am thinking i could do another loop that says that while column G (which only has information if updated in ) is empty then take the date in the respective cell in column A and keep opening files from the date in column A to yesterdays date? (pic for reference on what i mean) so it would fill every day from 13/09/2021 to 19/09/2021.

[image: Picture showing Columns A, B, F,G and H. With Dates in A and statistics in the rest]

Also it would be nice if anyone had any pointers about making this code more robust and/or efficient as I am quite new to VBA.

```
Sub OpenManagersFileAndSelectColumns()

Dim directory As String, fileName As String, sheet As Worksheet, total As Integer, directory3day As String, fileName3day As String, directory2day As String, fileName2day As String, DateStringFS As String, AlteryxFP As String

' Turn off screen updating and displaying alerts.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

' Creating Dynamic Elements for directories and file names.
    ' Create the year, day amd month year
    
        'For - 1 Days (used in two places)
        YearString = Format((Date - 1), "yyyy")
        MonthYearString = Format((Date - 1), "mmm yyyy")
        DateString = Format((Date - 1), "dd-mm-yyyy")
        
        'For - 2 Days
        YearString2day = Format((Date - 2), "yyyy")
        MonthYearString2day = Format((Date - 2), "mmm yyyy")
        DateString2day = Format((Date - 2), "dd-mm-yyyy")

        'For - 3 Days
        YearString3day = Format((Date - 3), "yyyy")
        MonthYearString3day = Format((Date - 3), "mmm yyyy")
        Dim DateString3day As String

        'Date for File Name
        DateStringFS = Format((Date), "dd.mm.yy")
 
    'Gets username of the device for comp and whether or not
    comp = Environ("username")

    'Gets Alteryx Output
    If Environ("username") = "SP" Then
        AlteryxFP = "Alteryx Output\"
    Else
        AlteryxFP = ""
    End If
    
    


' Initialize the variable directory. We use the Dir function to find the first *.csv ?? file stored in this directory. ( this can be changed to xls if necessary
    'For Today - 1 day (used in two places)
    directory = "C:\Users\" & comp & "\Dropbox (SHG)\" & AlteryxFP & "\Daily Finance & Revenue Data\1. Daily Occupancy Output\Site 5\" & YearString & "\" & MonthYearString & "\" & DateString & "\"
    
    'For Today - 2 Days
    directory2day = "C:\Users\" & comp & "\Dropbox (SHG)\" & AlteryxFP & "\Daily Finance & Revenue Data\1. Daily Occupancy Output\Site 5\" & YearString2day & "\" & MonthYearString2day & "\" & DateString2day & "\"
    
    'For Today - 3 Days
    directory3day = "C:\Users\" & comp & "\Dropbox (SHG)\" & AlteryxFP & "\Daily Finance & Revenue Data\1. Daily Occupancy Output\Site 5\" & MonthYearString3day & "\" & DateString3day & "\"



'Ensures the current file is activated and clears previous content.

Windows("YORYK Daily Report " & DateStringFS & "$.xlsb").Activate
Sheets("Actual data").Activate
Rows("4:7").Select
Selection.ClearContents

'If its a monday then it will open the last 3 days, it is the rest of the week it will open the previous day.
If Format(Date, "w") = 2 Then
    


    ' Today - 1 days
    
    fileName = Dir(directory & "*manager*.csv")
    
    ' The variable fileName now holds the name of the first Excel file found in the directory. Add a Do While Loop.
    Do While fileName <> ""

        ' There is no simple way to copy worksheets from closed Excel files. Therefore we open the Excel file.
        Workbooks.Open (directory & fileName), local:=True
            
        ' Import the sheets from the Excel file into import-sheet.xls.
        
        For Each sheet In Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets
            total = Workbooks("YORYK Daily Report " & DateStringFS & "$.xlsb").Worksheets.Count
            Windows(fileName).Activate
                
                ' If the date in the file is TODAY -1 then accept, otherwise error message.
                  If Range("AG2") = (Date - 1) Then
                  
                    Rows("2:2").Select
                    Selection.Copy
                    Windows("YORYK Daily Report " & DateStringFS & "$.xlsb").Activate
                    Sheets("Actual data").Activate
                    Rows("7:7").Select
                    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                    :=False, Transpose:=False
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                    Range("A4:AG5").Select
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                    
                Else
            
                    MsgBox "Date in file does not match " & DateString
                
                ' End If for checking the date for day - 1
                End If

                Next sheet
        
        'Close the Excel file.
        Workbooks(fileName).Close
        
        'The Dir function is a special function. To get the other Excel files, you can use the Dir function again with no arguments.
        fileName = Dir()
        
        'Note: When no more file names match, the Dir function returns a zero-length string ("").
        'As a result, Excel VBA will leave the Do While loop.
    
    'End of loop for day - 1 file open and paste.
    
    
    Loop
    
    ' Today - 2 days.
    
    fileName2day = Dir(directory2day & "*manager*.csv")
    
    ' The variable fileName now holds the name of the first Excel file found in the directory. Add a Do While Loop.
    Do While fileName2day <> ""

        ' There is no simple way to copy worksheets from closed Excel files. Therefore we open the Excel file.
        Workbooks.Open (directory2day & fileName2day), local:=True
        
        
        ' Import the sheets from the Excel file into this sheet.
        
        For Each sheet In Workbooks(fileName2day).Worksheets
            total = Workbooks("YORYK Daily Report " & DateStringFS & "$.xlsb").Worksheets.Count
            Windows(fileName2day).Activate
                
                If Range("AG2") = Date - 2 Then
                  
                    Rows("2:2").Select
                    Selection.Copy
            
                    Sheets("Actual data").Activate
                    Rows("6:6").Select
                    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                    :=False, Transpose:=False
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                
                Else
            
                    MsgBox "Date in file does not match " & DateString2day
            
                End If
        
        Next sheet
        
        'Close the Excel file.
        Workbooks(fileName2day).Close
        
        'The Dir function is a special function. To get the other Excel files, you can use the Dir function again with no arguments.
        fileName2day = Dir()
        
        'Note: When no more file names match, the Dir function returns a zero-length string ("").
        'As a result, Excel VBA will leave the Do While loop.

    Loop


    ' Today - 3 days
    
    fileName3day = Dir(directory3day & "*manager*.csv")
    
    ' The variable fileName now holds the name of the first Excel file found in the directory. Add a Do While Loop.
    Do While fileName3day <> ""

        ' There is no simple way to copy worksheets from closed Excel files. Therefore we open the Excel file.
        Workbooks.Open (directory3day & fileName3day), local:=True
        
        
        ' Import the sheets from the Excel file into import-sheet.xls.
        
        For Each sheet In Workbooks(fileName3day).Worksheets
            total = Workbooks("YORYK Daily Report " & DateStringFS & "$.xlsb").Worksheets.Count
            Windows(fileName3day).Activate
            
            'If Date in file is TODAY - 3 then accept and paste info otherwise error message.
                  
            If Range("AG2") = Date - 3 Then
                  
                Rows("1:2").Select
                Selection.Copy
                Windows("YORYK Daily Report " & DateStringFS & "$.xlsb").Activate
                Sheets("Actual data").Activate
                Rows("4:5").Select
                Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            
            Else
            
                MsgBox "Date in file does not match " & DateString3day
            
            ' End If for day - 3
            End If
    
        Next sheet
        
        'Close the Excel file.
        Workbooks(fileName3day).Close
        
        'The Dir function is a special function. To get the other Excel files, you can use the Dir function again with no arguments.
        fileName3day = Dir()
        
        'Note: When no more file names match, the Dir function returns a zero-length string ("").
        'As a result, Excel VBA will leave the Do While loop.


    'End Loop for Today  - 3
    Loop

   
    ' End of loop, now cleaning data, for 3 days section
    ' Next step is to select the right columns of data and run calculations to get TR, RR, OCC, OOO, ADR for the 3 day period.

    Range("A4:AF7").Select
    Selection.delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("K4:AD7").Select
    Selection.delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("AE4:DO7").Select
    Selection.delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("AF4:AT7").Select
    Selection.delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("AH4:CE7").Select
    Selection.delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("AE:AG").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Columns("C:C").Select
    Selection.INSERT Shift:=xlToRight
    Columns("F:M").Select
    Selection.INSERT Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    
    Windows("YORYK Daily Report " & DateStringFS & "$.xlsb").Activate
    Sheets("Actual data").Activate
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
    
    Range("G4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Rms"
    Range("H4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "G Rms"
    Range("I4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Rm Rev"
    Range("J4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "ADR"
    Range("K4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "OOO Rms"
    Range("L4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Total Rev"
    
    Range("G5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-4]+RC[-3]"
    Range("I5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-7]-RC[13]"
    Range("J5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]/RC[-3]"
    Range("K5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-6]"
    Range("L5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-10],RC[2]:RC[9])-SUM(RC[10]:RC[29])"
    Range("G5:L5").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("G5:L7"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("G5:L7").Select
    Range("G4").Select
       
' Colouring the titles to get notify it is done.

    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Rms"

    Range("H4").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "G Rms"

    Range("I4").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Rm Rev"

    Range("J4").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "ADR"

    Range("K4").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "OOO Rms"

    Range("L4").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Total Rev"
    Range("G4:L4").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    


' This else is for days where day does not = monday, so any other day of the week.

Else
    fileName = Dir(directory & "*manager*.csv")
    
    ' The variable fileName now holds the name of the first Excel file found in the directory. Add a Do While Loop.
    Do While fileName <> ""

        ' There is no simple way to copy worksheets from closed Excel files. Therefore we open the Excel file.
        Workbooks.Open (directory & fileName), local:=True
        
        
        ' Import the sheets from the forecast file into this sheet
        
        For Each sheet In Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets
            total = Workbooks("YORYK Daily Report " & DateStringFS & "$.xlsb").Worksheets.Count
            Windows(fileName).Activate
                   
            If Range("AG2") = Date - 1 Then

                Rows("1:2").Select
                Selection.Copy
                Windows("YORYK Daily Report " & DateStringFS & "$.xlsb").Activate
                Sheets("Actual data").Activate
                Rows("4:5").Select
                Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Else
            
                    MsgBox "Date in file does not match " & DateString
        
            End If
    
        Next sheet
        
        'Close the Excel file.
        Workbooks(fileName).Close
        
        
        'The Dir function is a special function. To get the other Excel files, you can use the Dir function again with no arguments.
        fileName = Dir()
        
        'Note: When no more file names match, the Dir function returns a zero-length string ("").
        'As a result, Excel VBA will leave the Do While loop.

    Loop
    
    ' End of loop, for 1 day set up, now cleaning data
    ' Next step is to select the right columns of data and run calculations to get TR, RR, OCC, OOO, ADR for one day

    Range("A4:AF7").Select
    Selection.delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("K4:AD7").Select
    Selection.delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("AE4:DO7").Select
    Selection.delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("AF4:AT7").Select
    Selection.delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("AH4:CE7").Select
    Selection.delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("AE:AG").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Columns("C:C").Select
    Selection.INSERT Shift:=xlToRight
    Columns("F:M").Select
    Selection.INSERT Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    
    Windows("YORYK Daily Report " & DateStringFS & "$.xlsb").Activate
    Sheets("Actual data").Activate
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
    
    Range("G4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Rms"
    Range("H4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "G Rms"
    Range("I4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Rm Rev"
    Range("J4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "ADR"
    Range("K4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "OOO Rms"
    Range("L4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Total Rev"
    
    Range("G5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-4]+RC[-3]"
    Range("I5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-7]-RC[13]"
    Range("J5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]/RC[-3]"
    Range("K5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-6]"
    Range("L5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-10],RC[2]:RC[9])-SUM(RC[10]:RC[29])"

    'Colour titles for each title to mark that its done, for one day.
    
    Range("G4").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Rms"

    Range("H4").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "G Rms"

    Range("I4").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Rm Rev"

    Range("J4").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "ADR"

    Range("K4").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "OOO Rms"

    Range("L4").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Total Rev"
    
    Range("G4:L4").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

' End If for -1 day vs - 3 day.
End If



'Turn on screen updating and displaying alerts again (outside the loop).
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Your code seems incomplete - no Sub to match the End Sub. And the picture is missing, looks like it has somehow got included at the end of the code panel

Comment: When you talk about last 7 days, do you mean 7 calendaristic days? I mean, running the code today, should the dates to be considered be in the range (13-09-2021 - 19-09-2021)?

Comment: Yes @FaneDuru, last 7 days from yesterday on a monday. so this week 13-19 but next Monday it would 20-26.

Comment: @JohnRC Sub & End Sub are both there. Sub OpenManagersFileAndSelectColumns() << is right at the beginning. Tom Brunberg updated the picture. thank you

Comment: A general comment: When manipulating sheets I think you would find it better to use variables to hold a reference sheets, instead of activating them and using implicit references to the activated sheet. So, instead of `Sheets("Actual data").Activate ... etc` it's better to use `Dim wsActualData as Worksheet, rRow6 as Range / Set wsActualData = Sheets("Actual data") / set rRow6 = wsActualData.Rows(6) / rRow6.PasteSpectial ... etc`

Comment: This should also help you to generalise the code a bit more so that you can loop round seven files instead of hard-coding all seven

Comment: Where you are setting interior formats, did you consider just defining a few custom styles, then just setting the style on the range? -A bit simpler for coding, and more flexible as you can easily change style definitions.

Comment: Are there, or could be **many csv files as "**manager*.csv" in each folder built for a specific day**, or only one such a file? Then iteration between the csv file sheets, since it may have only one?

Comment: What is `DateString` in `MsgBox "Date in file does not match " & DateString` message?

Comment: @FaneDuru as the people saving the files regularly make errors, i decided to use this method to allow it to open all of them, test them all for the correct info and then paste the one that is correct. DateString is yesterdays date. so that would appear if the date inside the file doesnt match the date in file path, which happens way too often!

Comment: I only meant that this variable never accepts a value in your code. So, talking about your question, it should be a date to match the name of each last child folder, where the csv file is searched for. But **you did not answer my question regarding possible existence of more csv files in one of the searched folders**...

Comment: There is no consistency in the way your code copies data. I mean for the first and the second (minus) day, it copy the second row to the 7, respectively 6 row of the template. Then, for the third minus day, is should copy rows 1:2 in rows 4-5? I tried creating a piece of code, but how can I imagine what to be copied in the following cases (-4 up to -7)? Then, the code following the iterations ruins what you already copied... "A4:AF7", "K4:AD7" and so on delete everything which has been copied during iterations.

Comment: @FaneDuru, my code is not inconsistent, on a monday i want both rows in the file so that  i know the headers are correct, this pastes in the first column (this would be day-3), on the 2nd day file only needs one row (without the headers), same for -1 days, this pastes them below each other instead of on top of each other which is why there are different rows.

Comment: Can you explain what is to be copied from each of the 7 csv files and where to be pasted (in the report)? I am not referring at the date comparison. It is your choice to compare. I've just observed that there is a variable there which never receives a value. And I am not talking about the code inconsistency! I am talking about what I deduce about your data to be processed, **looking to your code**.

Comment: @FaneDuru, it also doesnt delete everything, the original file has columns A-IC. so it deletes what we do not need.

Comment: @JohnRC Thanks for the suggestion, do you have any links on how to do this ? :) I am not sure of the phrasing that would get me the right result

Comment: OK. I can understand that it should be a huge row needing only part of it. Now **what is to be copied from each csv files and where in the report**? Is there a logic to be applied to all 7 days? You did not answer the question I asked twice: ** you did not answer my question regarding possible existence of more csv files in one of the searched folders**...

Comment: @FaneDuru, do not worry, i have got some starter answers from another user. thank you for your time.

Comment: This is nice. I will post a compact piece of code (I did until I couldn't understand what your code does) which creates arrays of the necessary (formatted date) strings and able co open each csv file (supposing that only one such a file exists, otherwise, the data copied will be overwritten, anyhow), copying their second row starting to the 7 row in the report and backwards until the first one. What is to be processed after copying the necessary data should come after. I hope you can deal with it, but **without selecting anything**.

Comment: @saffy do you still need examples? Not sure which of the suggestions I have made you are referring to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is Yes, you should probably change your code to to work down the list of dates so that it is being driven by the data. In addition, your code could benefit a lot from better use of vba which you can learn:

1. As noted in comments, use variables in your vba code to give access workbooks, worksheets and cell ranges instead of using `Activate` and `Select` - which should be used only if you need to change what the user sees and, even then, only right at the end of your processing, just before giving control back to the user. Your code will be easier to read and run much faster.
2. Use named formatting styles instead of hard-coding styles. This is much more meaningful and is much easier to change and extend if you want to improve the appearance of your workbook without having to change the vba code.
3. Divide the code up into functions that do a specific parts of the logic, and call the functions instead of repeating the code. If you use variables to refer to workbooks, worksheets etc, then you can pass variables to the functions. For example, the code that processes one csv file could be written as a function that is called from higher-level logic.

I think you will find that your code becomes a lot simpler and easier to read and understand.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next code. It is not tested, of course, but its logic should be correctly applied. It opens each csv file and copy its second row to the report starting from the 7th row, backwards to the first row:

```
Sub tes7DaysBackArray()
   Dim arr7D, arrM, arrY, d As Date, DateStringFS As String, wsAD As Worksheet, wbLoc As Workbook, AlteryxFP As String
   Dim pathRoot As String, fileName As String, comp As String, ws As Worksheet, i As Long, iRow As Long
   
  
   DateStringFS = Format((Date), "dd.mm.yy"): d = Date: iRow = 7
   'build arrays containing the necessary formatted strinns:
   arr7D = Application.Transpose(Evaluate("TEXT(DATE(" & Year(d - 7) & "," & month(d - 7) & ",row(" & Day(d - 7) & ":" & Day(d - 1) & ")),""dd-mm-yyyy"")"))
   arrM = Application.Transpose(Evaluate("TEXT(DATE(" & Year(d - 7) & "," & month(d - 7) & ",row(" & Day(d - 7) & ":" & Day(d - 1) & ")),""mmm yyy"")"))
   arrY = Application.Transpose(Evaluate("TEXT(DATE(" & Year(d - 7) & "," & month(d - 7) & ",row(" & Day(d - 7) & ":" & Day(d - 1) & ")),""yyyy"")"))
   Debug.Print Join(arr7D, "|"): Debug.Print Join(arrM, "|"): Debug.Print Join(arrY, "|") 'just to visually see the above built arrays...
   
    If Environ("username") = "SP" Then
        AlteryxFP = "Alteryx Output\"
    Else
        AlteryxFP = ""
    End If
     pathRoot = "C:\Users\" & comp & "\Dropbox (SHG)\" & AlteryxFP & "\Daily Finance & Revenue Data\1. Daily Occupancy Output\Site 5\"
   Set wsAD = Workbooks("YORYK Daily Report " & DateStringFS & "$.xlsb").Sheets("Actual data")
   For i = 0 To UBound(arr7D)
        fileName = pathRoot & arrY(i) & "\" & arrM(i) & "\" & arr7D(i) & "\"
                                                                                         
        fileName = dir(fileName & "*manager*.csv")
        If fileName <> "" Then
            Set wbLoc = Workbooks.Open(Directory & fileName, local:=True)
            Set ws = wbLoc.Sheets(1) 'the single existing sheet
             If CStr(Format(ws.Range("AG2").Value, "dd-mm-yyyy")) = arr7D(i) Then
                    wsAD.rows(iRow & ":" & iRow).Value = ws.rows("2:2").Value: iRow = iRow + 1
                    wbLoc.Close False
             Else
                    MsgBox "Date in file does not match " & arr7D(i)
             End If
        Else
            MsgBox "No any required csv file could be found in & """ & fileName & """."
        End If
   Next i
End Sub
```